# Execute function on every route/Action in Symfony3

Tags: symfony

I have a logging function that tracks pageloads. I would like to add that to every route that I already have in Symfony.

Currently I am doing it like this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/test", name="test")
 */
public function testAction(Request $request)
{


    /* Function to register pageload */
    $this->get('statsd')->countMetric('visitor.'.$request->get('_route'));


    return $this->render('default/indexFull.html.twig', array());

}
```

I could of course add that line to every route, but since I am new to Symfony I thought there might be a more elegant approach?

Any hint appreciated!

Comment: Make service to listen to event `kernel.request`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Symfony triggers events during the handling of a request. One of these events is the `kernel.request` event, which is executed before each controller.

Be aware that the router will do the matching during this event as well, so you need to make sure your listener is executed *after* the router listener. This can be done by using priorities.

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;

class CountMetricLogger
{
    // ...

    public function logVisit(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $this->statsd->countMetric('visitor.'.$event->getRequest()->get('_route'));
    }
}
```

```yaml
# app/config/services.yml
app.metric_logger:
    class: AppBundle\EventListener\CountMetricLogger
    arguments: ['@statsd']
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: logVisit }
```

More information:

- ["The kernel.request Event"](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel/introduction#the-kernel-request-event)
- ["The EventDispatcher component"](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/event_dispatcher/introduction.html)
- ["How to Create Event Listeners and Subscribers"](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/event_listener.html)